# How to get exact macth first next followed matches in elastic search

Tags: shell, elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic search, I need to search the words with particular word match
ex: I have words as

> cricketnplay, cricket23, cricket, criketlegend

when I search a word **cricket**
the result will be like 1st one exact match and next followed matches

- cricket
- cricket23
- cricketlegend
- cricketnplay

*how to query to get output like this please help,*
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You need to search with `_search` query.

```
GET /twitter/tweet/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { <field> : "cricket" }
    }
}
```

This query will return all matched elements with match score sorted in descending order of score.

Read more about `_search` query [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html)

Comment: I didn't get exact match 1st

Comment: can you send output ?